# How can show Persian Calendar in DevExpress DateEdit

Tags: devexpress, persian-calendar

I want to use DevExpress DateEdit with Persian Calendar in visual studio. I tried blew code but it wasn't work. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
Public Sub ToPersian(DateTimePicker As DevExpress.XtraEditors.DateEdit)
    Dim shamsi As New System.Globalization.PersianCalendar
    Dim PersianToday As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(shamsi.GetYear(DateTime.Now) & "/" & shamsi.GetMonth(DateTime.Now) & "/" & shamsi.GetDayOfMonth(DateTime.Now))
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-IR")
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-IR")

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames = New String() {"فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", ""}
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames = New String() {"فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", ""}
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = New String() {"فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", ""}
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = New String() {"فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", ""}
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames = New String() {"ی", "د", "س", "چ", "پ", "ج", "ش"}
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortestDayNames = New String() {"ی", "د", "س", "چ", "پ", "ج", "ش"}
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames = New String() {"یکشنبه", "دوشنبه", "ﺳﻪشنبه", "چهارشنبه", "پنجشنبه", "جمعه", "شنبه"}
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator = "ق.ظ"
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator = "ب.ظ"
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm"
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/"
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.SetAllDateTimePatterns(New String() {"dd/MM/yyyy"}, "d"c)
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.SetAllDateTimePatterns(New String() {"dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"}, "D"c)
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.SetAllDateTimePatterns(New String() {"yyyy MMMM"}, "y"c)
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.SetAllDateTimePatterns(New String() {"yyyy MMMM"}, "Y"c)

    DateTimePicker.EditValue = PersianToday
    DateTimePicker.Properties.TodayDate = PersianToday
    DateTimePicker.Properties.EditFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime
    DateTimePicker.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime
    DateTimePicker.Properties.FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday
    DateTimePicker.Properties.EditMask = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    DateTimePicker.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = True
    DateTimePicker.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what does not work? What is the result of executing the code you've posted? DevExpress has said themselves that they do not support a Persian calendar and has no immediate plans to. https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T272987/how-to-set-persiancalendar-to-dateedit-control

Comment: @Brendon
Thanks for your attention Brendon. I saw all those articles before. I want to customize DevExpress control for Persian calendar. I know this is possible but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: What makes you say this is even possible?

Comment: @Brendon
Because I saw customized DateEdit for Persian calendar. But I want to do it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Just add following lines of the codes into your `Program.cs` file in your project. it works fine in my projects:

```
static void Main()
{
    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fa-IR");

    // The following line provides localization for the application's user interface. 
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

    // The following line provides localization for data formats.  
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;

    // Set this culture as the default culture for all threads in this application.  
    // Note: The following properties are supported in the .NET Framework 4.5+ 
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;


    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```